# Upload video from ios device using ionic/cordova to django rest-framework file field

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django-rest-framework, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a video from an Ionic app to django device.

1. I am using $cordovaCamera.getPicture to grab the video from the photo gallery of the device.
2. I am using ng-file-upload to upload the video.
3. On the django rest-framework side I have this on the ViewSet:

   ```
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       f = self.request.data.get('file')
       serializer.save(file=f)
   ```

JS upload looks like this:

```
var url = 'http://ip...'
Upload.upload({
            url: url,
            data: params,
            headers: {'Authorization': "Token " + token,
                "Content-Type": 'video/'+ext},
        }).then(onSuccess, function (resp)
        { ...
```

Here are the headers:

```
POST http://10.100.102.8:83/image/?content=business
REMOTE_ADDR=10.100.102.4
CONTENT_LENGTH=442

CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundarywbpGxg45jBTAQmun
HTTP_ACCEPT=application/json, text/plain, */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-us
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=Token 032c6d410a11352d57cb8958b0d4aaf991c
HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
HTTP_HOST=10.100.102.8:83
HTTP_ORIGIN=file://
HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2 like Mac OS 
X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15C107 
(1455558801991342)
```

And the 400 Http Response I get:

```
400 400
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

- With videos from the web browser it is working fine.
- With Images it works well from both browser and device.
- When uploading images I am converting the image to base64.

I keep getting 400 error log with no extra info when uploading a video from device.

Any advice?

Comment: It will be quite hard to diagnose this without the HTTP response. Can you change your log settings to capture 400 errors? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django-request

Comment: Hello Symmetric, thank you for your help.
I have edit my question with the HTTP response and the request headers. 

Is there any other way to get more info about the 400 response?

Comment: Hmm, django isn't giving you much help here. Can you reproduce the problem locally, if you manually POST your payload to the development server? If so, I'd try step-debugging the request through the stack to see what's going wrong.